# SQL list account managers with predecessor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to get a list of account managers on an account, their start/end date and the new account manager that took over the account on a single row.

Example:

```
DECLARE @accountManagerListing TABLE 
                               (
                                    accountNumber INT,
                                    accountManager VARCHAR(8),
                                    accountManagerStartDate DATE,
                                    accountManagerEndDate DATE
                               )

INSERT INTO @accountManagerListing (accountNumber, accountManager, accountManagerStartDate, accountManagerEndDate)
VALUES  (1, 'asmith', '01/01/2001', '01/31/2001'),
        (1, 'bsmith', '02/01/2001', '03/01/2002'),
        (1, 'csmith', '03/02/2002', '03/10/2002'),
        (1, 'dsmith', '03/11/2002', '06/01/2017'),
        (1, 'esmith', '06/02/2017', '08/17/2018'),
        (2, 'fsmith', '02/11/2018', '06/01/2018'),
        (2, 'gsmith', '06/02/2018', null)
```

Expected results:

```
Account Number  Old Account Manager  New Account Manager  Start Date  End Date

1                                    asmith               01/01/2001   01/31/2001
1               asmith               bsmith               02/01/2001   03/01/2002
1               bsmith               csmith               03/02/2002   03/10/2002
1               csmith               dsmith               03/11/2002   06/01/2017
1               dsmith               esmith               06/02/2017   08/17/2018
2                                    fsmith               02/11/2018   06/01/2018
2               fsmith               gsmith               06/02/2018   NULL
```

Comment: I'd like to applaud you for, on your first post ever, including sample data and expected results with DDL. Impressive. One thing though, I would also tag your flavor of SQL (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: what type of database are you using? are you able to use `WINDOW` functions?

Comment: The code is clearly SQL Server, so I've added the tag.

Comment: so this is for a SQL Server database. Using Lag() did work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `lag()` :

```
select a.*, 
      lag(accountManager) over (partition by accountnumber order by accountManagerStartDate) as OldAccountManager
from @accountManagerListing a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select aml.*, amlprev.accountmanager as old_accountmanager
from @accountManagerListing aml left join
     @accountManagerListing amlprev
     on amlprev.accountnumber = aml.accountnumber and
        amlprev.enddate = dateadd(day, -1, aml.startdate);
```

This finds the *immediately* preceding manager (if any).  If there is a gap, then this returns no manager.  This logic seems more aligned with your description of "took over".